# SQL: How can I get the value of an attribute in XML datatype?

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, xslt, xquery

I have the following xml in my database:

```
<email>
  <account language="en" ... />
</email>
```

I am using something like this now: but still have to find the attribute value.

```
 SELECT convert(xml,m.Body).query('/Email/Account')
 FROM Mail
```

How can I get the value of the `language` attribute in my select statement with SQL?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use XQuery:

```
declare @xml xml =
'<email>
  <account language="en" />
</email>'

select @xml.value('(/email/account/@language)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

---

```
declare @t table (m xml)

insert @t values 
    ('<email><account language="en" /></email>'), 
    ('<email><account language="fr" /></email>')

select m.value('(/email/account/@language)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from @t
```

Output:

```
en
fr
```

Comment: this worked perfect! 
select @xml.value('(/email/account/@language)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') 
THANK YOU!

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk What if a root element contains an `xmlns` attribute? Say, `<email xmlns="http://domain.com/ws/2016-08-07>`. In this case XQuery returns `NULL`.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown, this is called "Default namespace". Something like this: set namespace before `select` command like this: `WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://domain.com/ws/2016-08-07' as x )`. Then you can add reference to this namespace in the select query: `'(/x:email/x:account/@language)[1]'`

Answer (score 17):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml = N'<email><account language="en" /></email>'

SELECT T.C.value('@language', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @xml.nodes('email/account') T(C)
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends a lot on how you're querying the document. You can do this, though:

```
CREATE TABLE #example (
   document NText
);
INSERT INTO #example (document)
SELECT N'<email><account language="en" /></email>';

WITH XmlExample AS (
  SELECT CONVERT(XML, document) doc
  FROM #example
)
SELECT
  C.value('@language', 'VarChar(2)') lang
FROM XmlExample CROSS APPLY
     XmlExample.doc.nodes('//account') X(C);

DROP TABLE #example;
```

**EDIT** after changes to your question.

Comment: I've edited my question. the xml is saved as ntext in the database. I convert it first to xml type.

Comment: See my edits, using `ntext` input and a table approach with CTE to transform to `xml`.

Answer (score 3):

if the xml data is stored in sql server as a string column then use cast

```
select cast(your_field as XML)
       .value('(/email/account/@language)[1]', 'varchar(20)') 
from your_table
```