# find and split in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how can i find and split a value between double quotation 
Value is like this :

```
'<Relations mfrid="EnvoeyName_MFR"><Form EC="180" ETC="711" Val="1679" /></Relations>'
```

value is one filed of table and i want split "EC,ETC,Val" value
i mean 180,711,1679

thanks for your help

Comment: I assume you are trying to extract the attribute values from an XML datatype. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808652/sql-how-can-i-get-the-value-of-an-attribute-in-xml-datatype) question. Googling "t-sql xml query attribute value" will give other examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can try the following

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML = '<Relations mfrid="EnvoeyName_MFR"><Form EC="180" ETC="711" Val="1679" /></Relations>'

SELECT
    EC = Node.Data.value('@EC', 'INT'),
    ETC = Node.Data.value('@ETC', 'INT'),
    Val = Node.Data.value('@EC', 'INT')
    FROM @XMLData.nodes('/Relations/Form') Node(Data)
```

Comment: hey buddy , i have another question 
when i execute that query , I found some value like this :

<Relations mfrid="SubjectMjless_MFR"><Form EC="41" ETC="712" Value="55" /></Relations>  

so that code can't get EC value from tag Form

<Form EC="41" ETC="712" Value="55" />

Comment: I'm able to get the values even if there are multiple Tags, so there might be some issue with your tag or query. Can you share more details ?